# Why does __init__() have to be used twice when I inherit from another class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, tkinter

I apologize if the question is not a correct statement about what is going on or it turns out to be specific for the example that I describe. It is just what I noticed. I have been learning how to make GUIs using Tkinter in Python 2.7 and I have followed several tutorials, and I have seen several different styles for structuring the code.

One way is the following:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My App")
root.mainloop()
```

The other way I have seen is:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.title("My App")

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

The second method creates a class `App` that inherits from the `tk.Tk` class, thus making `App` a subclass of `tk.Tk`? `def __init__(self):` is the constructor for class `App` I am defining. But then I must also call the `__init__()` function from the `tk.Tk` class as well. If that is true, why is that? When I just run `root = tk.Tk()`, its `__init__()` function is called then?

Comment: When you define `__init__`, the already defined method is overwritten.  Therefore, the `__init__` method that your class inherited from `tk.Tk` is not called, so you need to do it explicitly in your method.

Comment: The first way calls the `init` for the `Tk` class, while the second calls the `init` for your `App` class. Remeber that, `Tk` is not instantiated when you instantiate an object for your `App` class. You need to call it's constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you run `root=tk.Tk()` then an instance of the class `tk.Tk` is instantiated -- which means calling the `__init__` of this class.

In the second method you want to create a new class -- which might be useful especially in a larger project, to be able to port it anywhere else. 
You cannot append something to the parent's `__init__` method, you can just override it by defining it anew. So if you still want all the useful stuff to happen, which is executed in the `tk.Tk.__init__()`, you have to call it explicitly.

One might argue, that a better style would be to use `super()` instead of hardcoding the parent class name. But this gets relevant in still more complicated projects...

Comment: In python 2.x you can't use super, because the tkinter classes are old style classes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class object, it's constructor gets called automatically. This is what is happening in both snippets. The first one instantiates an object for the `Tk` class so therefore the `__init__` method for the `Tk` class gets called. Where in the second way, you are not creating an object for the `Tk` class. You are creating an object for your `App` class. This does not mean it will call the constructor for the class that it has inherited from. You need to call it explicitly.